# Monitor file to find which thread is modifying file

Tags: java, monitoring

I want to find which java thread is modifying file. 
If anybody know tool or know how we can monitor and get thread name please share.

Thanks.

Comment: There is something called [WatcherService](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes), I'm not sure if it can be utilized for your purpose !!!

Comment: Thanks guys for your response but thing is I don't have access to code that's why I asked tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why exactly you need this information but i beleive there are two ways.

First way is in your java code when you create a thread , create it with a name. There are constructors & method available in Thread class to do the same. If you have a good logging in your project then you can log the thread name who enters the code to modify the file.

Second way is again dependent on having a thread with the name. You can use a java profiler to find out what threads are doing at a point in time. Although it will be too tough if threads are modifying the file too quickly. But if you are trying to find a problem of slow modification of file by a thread then profiler may give you the hint.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if the file modification is a code that you wrote, you can use before the modification:

```
Thread.currentThread().getName();
Thread.currentThread().getId();
```

and youl get the name and id of the thread